# Editing a WPF ListView Item at runtime from c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to edit a WPF listview item from c# at runtime but I dont know how to do it.In WindowsForms I was using:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    if (item.SubItems[2].Text == id)
    {
        if (pingtime != 0)
            item.SubItems[6].Text = pingtime.ToString();
        else item.SubItems[6].Text = "999";
    }
}
```

but this is not working because in WPF there is no `Item.SubItems[]`. 
What I need to do is to find the item that contains the right id, and then to edit the 6th column of the item with the new value.
How can I do it in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding in WPF differently from WinForms. For list views, the data source will be an ObservableCollection. Type T is your custom class type. Through XAML code, using  data template on the ListView you can describe how properties on your custom class type are displayed for each data item.

If you want to update the value of a specific items, you need to change the collection , your collection should implement  INotifyPropertyChanged interface

**Code:**

```
internal class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees= new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

    // Populate Employee
}

public class MyWindow
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding Path=Employee, Mode=OneWay}>
    <ListView.DataTemplate>
        <Label Content={Binding Path=EmployeeName, Mode=OneWay} />
     </ListView.DataTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If you still want to access using code behind, you can try this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
         if (((yourclass)listView1.Items[i]).id== "6")
         {
                //change it here
         }
}
```